# SQL query not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am using the standard ASP.NET Membership table structure in SQL Server and was doing a bit of manually querying in Management studio and ran this query

```
SELECT *
FROM [aspnet_Users]
WHERE UserId = '2ac5dd56-2630-406a-9fb8-d4445bc781da&cID=49'
```

Notice the &cID=49 at the end - I copied this from a querystring and forgot to remove that part.

However, to my surprise it returned the data correctly (there is a user with the ID 2ac5dd56-2630-406a-9fb8-d4445bc781da) - any idea why this works? To my mind it should not match or probably more likely throw an error as it shouldn't be able to convert to a Guid?

Comment: what is the value excatly at DB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`uniqueidentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) type is considered a character type for the purposes of conversion from a character expression, and therefore is subject to the truncation rules for converting to a character type. That is, when character expressions are converted to a character data type of a different size, **values that are too long for the new data type are truncated**.

Because the uniqueidentifier type **is limited to 36 characters**, the characters that exceed that length are truncated.

<sub>Note that above is quoted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)</sub>

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense now but I agree it is strange - if I pass in a value that is less than 36 chars then I get a conversion error so my expectation would be that if I passed in more then it would also fail!

Answer (score 2):

The parser is (remarkably) lenient when converting string literals to guid literals, apparently:

```
SELECT CAST('E63F4FFC-8574-428B-B6B8-95CFCA05ED52' AS uniqueidentifier)
SELECT CAST('E63F4FFC-8574-428B-B6B8-95CFCA05ED52a' AS uniqueidentifier)
SELECT CAST('E63F4FFC-8574-428B-B6B8-95CFCA05ED52-!' AS uniqueidentifier)
SELECT CAST('E63F4FFC-8574-428B-B6B8-95CFCA05ED52~#5' AS uniqueidentifier)
SELECT CAST('E63F4FFC-8574-428B-B6B8-95CFCA05ED52$3%] ' AS uniqueidentifier)
```

all give the same result, no errors.

[This is documented behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx), so we can't really complain:

> The following example demonstrates the truncation of data when the
>   value is too long for the data type being converted to. Because the
>   uniqueidentifier type is limited to 36 characters, the characters that
>   exceed that length are truncated.
>
> ```
> DECLARE @ID nvarchar(max) = N'0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0wrong';
> SELECT @ID, CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, @ID) AS TruncatedValue;
> ```
>
> Here is the result set.
>
> ```
> String                                       TruncatedValue
> -------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------
> 0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0wrong    0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I understand now - does seem an odd one though!